# Setup public IP address on LXC container

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ip, lxc

Can anyone tell me how to setup a network interface for each LXC container so that each container can have its own dedicated IP address?

Here's what the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on my host node looks like:

```
# Generated by SolusVM

 auto lo
  iface lo inet loopback

 auto eth0
  iface eth0 inet static
   address 160.201.10.167
   gateway 160.201.8.1
   netmask 255.255.252.0
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

 auto eth0:0
  iface eth0:0 inet static
   address 160.201.8.32
   gateway 160.201.8.1
   netmask 255.255.252.0
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

 auto eth0:1
  iface eth0:1 inet static
   address 160.201.8.36
   gateway 160.201.8.1
   netmask 255.255.252.0
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4

 auto eth0:2
  iface eth0:2 inet static
   address 160.201.8.37
   gateway 160.201.8.1
   netmask 255.255.252.0
   dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

Here's what my LXC container config file looks like:

```
lxc.include = /usr/share/lxc/config/ubuntu.common.conf
lxc.rootfs = /var/lib/lxc/francis/rootfs
lxc.mount = /var/lib/lxc/francis/fstab
lxc.utsname = francis
lxc.arch = amd64
lxc.network.type = veth
lxc.network.flags = up
lxc.network.link = eth0
lxc.network.hwaddr = 00:16:3e:de:53:6f
lxc.network.ipv4 = 160.201.8.32
lxc.cgroup.memory.limit_in_bytes = 256M
lxc.cgroup.memory.memsw.limit_in_bytes = 256M
```

Can anyone show me how to give the container "francis" its own public IP address, like `160.201.8.32` for example?

My host node is running Ubuntu 14.04 Server.